# `exec /bin/bash -il` fails in .profile

Tags: command-line, bash, login, .profile

The Bash manpage says:

> After reading that file (/etc/profile), it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

So if I have both a `~/.bash_profile` and a `~/.profile`, only the first will be run.

Because I often share a HOME between different systems I have both, hard linked. On 18.04.2 a login returns to the login screen. With each as a separate but identical file, the same happens. To share between systems and available shells my `.profile` contains a `case` statement based on `$0`, setting up as appropriate or executing a preferred shell. Effectively it does:

```
case $0 in
*bash) ... some stuff ...
;;
*) exec /bin/bash -il
;;
esac
```

Putting a `#` before the `exec` in the `.profile` copy and all works well...

The `.bash_profile` is identical (apart from the `#` in `.profile` when I insert one).

It turns out that 18.04.2 is quite happy with that `exec` in `~/.bash_profile`, but not in `~/.profile` (which it shouldn't be reading anyway). When it's there, logging in takes the password → black screen briefly → login window again. When it's commented out, login happens properly. Also the shell is Bash, so that branch of the case shouldn't be being taken either.

Thoughts?

Comment: The code is just
  "exec /bin/bash -il" (no quotes) 
and when it's there, logging in takes the password -> black screen briefly -> login window again. When it's commented out login happens properly.

Comment: To be more complete, the .profile (and .bash_profile) in effect  do a "case $0 in *bash) ... some stuff ... ;; *) exec /bin/bash -il ;; esac"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI login process may source `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` for setting up environment variables, etc., and it may use `/bin/dash` or `/bin/bash` for that. Ask Ubuntu has many instances of GUI login failing because of errors in `~/.profile` or `/etc/profile`. You shouldn't be `exec`'ing something else in these files without checking for interactive usage at the very least. For example, the default `.bashrc` has this at the top, which you could adapt:

```
~ head /etc/skel/.bashrc 
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Comment: So you are saying that the GUI login process reads these files before the user shell starts? If that's the case then I can see that using exec could cause problems. Of course only a login shell would read these files, so it's not normally a problem. I've been using this basic construct for around 30 years on various flavours of Unix. I do understand that Linux is different, but some differences, like this, are quite subtle.

Comment: @davidledger yes, because often environment variables that affect GUI programs (say Java ones with CLASSPATH, etc.) are set there so a login shell is specifically run to source them. For example, here's a bug report from some time ago when LightDM didn't source these: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/794315